# Solr unexpected results with parentheses

Tags: solr, parentheses

This query returns 8346 results:

```
(respiratory failure) AND NOT ("heart failure", "renal insufficiency")
```

but without the first set of parentheses it returns 2297 only:

```
respiratory failure AND NOT ("heart failure", "renal insufficiency")
```

Why are parentheses behaving like that? if anything, I would expect the first query to return less records.

I am puzzled...

Comment: debugQuery=true should tell you exactly how the query was parsed

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Bizzare output. Here are the results. With parentheses: "+(_text_:respiratory _text_:failure) -(PhraseQuery(_text_:\"heart failure\") PhraseQuery(_text_:\"renal insufficiency\"))" ----Without parentheses: "_text_:respiratory +_text_:failure -(PhraseQuery(_text_:\"heart failure\") PhraseQuery(_text_:\"renal insufficiency\"))".  So, contrary to what I expected, it adds a '+' between "respiratory" and failure when no parentheses used.

Comment: Sorry, text editor is removing undescore from my comments. Where you read "text" it is instead the usual Solr catch-all field with leading and trailing underscore

Comment: You can escape those with \\ in front of the underscore. The second parses failure as required (and respiratory as optional), while the first parses as either respiratory or failure is required.

Comment: Cannot upvote because your reply is in the comments, but thank you very much.